# What could cause trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)?

Tags: linux, signals

I hope to have an understanding of this signal and some possible suggestions of why this signal would occur.

I had this bug when I was writing a binary rewritter on linux.

I was hoping for some suggestions since I couldn't find any proper explanation on this bug.

All the issues related I find online are application specific, so they don't provide proper reasoning for this signal.

I'm confused about this bug because I didn't do anything tracing when running this program and this bug seems could only be triggered if the program is being traced.

For more details, I was loading the dynamic linker(ld) into the memory in my program and then transfer the control to it so that it could dynamically link and load a program at run time. But it sends this signal when the control is transferred to the linker(ld) in the memory.

Comment: Can't see code! What havo you done, what error message, debugger output, strace used?. My crystal ball is broken today ;)

Comment: Thanks, your right, this is a duplicate, I'll delete it later

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that answer careful enough